# Problems with Passenger on Apache

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger, rack, middleware

I'm having troubles deploying a rack application with [rack-http-logger](https://github.com/mattt/rack-http-logger) middleware on Passenger Apache version. The problem is that Apache doesn't accept LOG method requests, which this middleware is interpreting, so I'm trying to use POST instead.

This is my config.ru:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

$stdout.sync = true

use Rack::HTTPLogger, :method => 'POST'
run lambda { [404, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, ['Page Not Found']] }
```

Everything is working fine on Thin, but I'm having this error on Passenger:

```
App 57235 stderr: [ 2014-04-30 08:30:05.9440 57256/0x007ffe8c018af0(Worker 1) utils.rb:68 ]: 
*** Exception ArgumentError in Rack application object (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)) (process 57256, thread 0x007ffe8c018af0(Worker 1)):
App 57235 stderr:   from config.ru:7:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
App 57235 stderr:   from /Users/apps/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rack-http-logger-0.1.0/lib/rack/http-logger.rb:17:in `call'
App 57235 stderr:   from /Users/apps/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/rack-http-logger-0.1.0/lib/rack/http-logger.rb:17:in `call'
App 57235 stderr:   from /Users/apps/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.41/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
App 57235 stderr:   from /Users/apps/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.41/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
App 57235 stderr:   from /Users/apps/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.41/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
App 57235 stderr:   from /Users/apps/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/gems/passenger-4.0.41/lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
[Wed Apr 30 08:30:05 2014] [error] [client 172.20.16.168] Premature end of script headers:
```

Any ideas of what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you investigate "Exception ArgumentError in Rack application object (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0))"?

Comment: Yes, the thing is that this code is working under Thin with Foreman, that is what makes me think that this could be a Passenger problem.

Comment: It sounds like we've a very different definition of investigating… What's that invalid argument, and how/why is it being set?

Comment: I'm guessing that `:method => 'POST'` is being passed wrong? But rack-http-logger docs says it's a valid option.

Comment: No, no, no: not guessing. Dive into the Rake and/or Passenger and/or other code, and use `p` or `pp` to identify *what* is being passed, straight out from the code. And then use `caller` to identify the reason it's getting passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application object (the lambda that that you pass to `run`) does not conform to [the Rack specification](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html). According to the specification, it must accept exactly 1 argument, but your lambda accepts none and so you get an ArgumentError.

Phusion Passenger implements Rack differently than Thin does. Because the Rack specification does not specify how spec violations should be handled, each server handles it differently. This is why some (wrong) code which works on Thin, may not work on Phusion Passenger, and vice versa.

Comment: I get it now, it clearly was my mistake. Thanks a lot.